# Interact with python subprocess once waits for user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm working on a script to automate tests of a certain software, and as part of it I need to chech if it runs commands correctly.

I'm currently launching an executeable using subprocess and passing the initial parameters.
My code is: `subprocess.run("program.exe get -n WiiVNC", shell=True, check=True)`
As far as I understand, this runs the executeable, and is supposed to return an exception if the exit code is 1.

Now, the program launches, but at some point waits for user input like so:
[image: Required user input]

My question is, how do I go about submitting the user input "y" using subprocess once either, the text "Continue with download of "WiiVNC"? (y/n) >" shows up, or once the program waits for user input.

Comment: Could you please try this. Assign subprocess result in a variable. `p = subprocess.run("program.exe get -n WiiVNC", shell=True, check=True)` and try to send keys `p.stdin.write(b'y\n')`

Comment: @ErdoganOnal doesn't seem to work, `Cannot find reference 'stdin' in 'CompletedProcess | CompletedProcess'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("program.exe get -n WiiVNC", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
process.stdin.write(b"y\n")
process.stdin.flush()
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Comment: Hello @ErdoganOnal, your solution worked but I have a problem, I have to run it inside a docker, any idea on why inside a docker doesn't work? It just doesn't display the interactive shell and for that it crashes

Answer (score 2):

You should use the pexpect module for all complicated subprocessing. In particular, the module is designed to handle the complicated case of either passing through the input to the current process for the user to answer and/or allowing your script to answer the input for the user and continue the subprocess.

Added some code for an example:

```
### File Temp ### 
# #!/bin/env python
# x = input('Type something:')
# print(x)

import pexpect

x = pexpect.spawn('python temp') #Start subprocess. 
x.interact()                     #Imbed subprocess in current process. 

# or

x = pexpect.spawn('python temp') #Start subprocess.
find_this_output = x.expect(['Type something:'])
if find_this_output is 0:
    x.send('I type this in for subprocess because I found the 0th string.')
```

Comment: Huh, thanks. Mind to add example code on how I can go about allowing my script to answer the input for the user?

Comment: Note that the code will halt at the x.expect() line waiting for the things you specify, you can tell it to wait for a string, or pexpect.EOF, etc. You can also set a timer of how long to wait. If it returns, it means if found something in the list and returns the index.